# How do I selectively delete drawings in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am drawing a lot of **moving particles** in a **stationary box** with `Tkinter`. My box is always there and does not change as time goes by, whereas the particles need to be updated.

My first intuition is to delete ALL the things (both particles and the box) and then redraw everything.

```
canvas.delete(ALL)
```

It indeed **works**, **but** the frame updates get **extremely slow**. This is because my box is of an irregular shape, which implies that I have to draw the box dot by dot. So this delete-everything-and-redraw-everything method is unsatisfactory.

I wish that the **box is drawn only once**, and **only the particles get deleted and redrawn (updated)**. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a rectangle on `canvas`:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
```

This would return a `handle`, so if you keep track of it,

```
myRectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
canvas.delete(myRectangle)
```

This will delete only the myRectangle object.

Another way of doing it is to use tags.

```
canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, tags="myRectangle")
canvas.delete("myRectangle")
```

Comment: +1 and thanks. The hassle is that as I mentioned, my box is of irregular shapes. So I plot the box by plotting many many dots. So using this method, I will have thousands of handles...

Comment: What do you want to update? You always have itemconfig or config to help you reconfig an element and you don't have to redraw it.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need to do "draw the box dot by dot", as Tkinter has a create_polygon method as I remember. Can you elaborate more on your question?(including a picture to illustrate your problem).

Comment: The tags method works fine for me, but it is still quite slow. Not sure it is the fastest that one can achieve or I did sth. wrong

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is assign the drawings to variables, and then delete those.  The below script demonstrates this:

```
from Tkinter import Button, Canvas, Tk

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas()
canvas.grid()

drawing1 = canvas.create_oval((10,50,20,60), fill="red")
drawing2 = canvas.create_oval((30,70,40,80), fill="blue")

Button(text="Kill 1", command=lambda: canvas.delete(drawing1)).grid()
Button(text="Kill 2", command=lambda: canvas.delete(drawing2)).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

In addition to `ALL`, the `delete` method can also accept a specific drawing.

Comment: +1 and thx! The hassle is that as I mentioned, my box is of irregular shapes. So I plot the box by plotting many many dots. So using this method, I will have thousands of handles...

Comment: @mavErick - Well, why not make a list and then append each dot to the list?  Then, you can delete them by index.  For example `canvas.delete(mylist[45])` will delete dot number 46 (remember that Python indexes start at 0).  I know it will be a little bulky, but it should be a lot faster than deleting every dot and then redrawing them all every time.

Comment: You can also associate tags with items, and then delete things by tag.  This allows you to group objects together and delete, move or reconfigure them in a single statement.